# When and how to set a status of anything to "Expired"?

Tags: c#, database-design

Example:

I have a class of an abstract request:

```
public enum RequestStatus
{
   Active,
   Cancelled,
   Expired
}

public class SomethingRequest
{
    public RequestStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The problem I stumbled upon:

1. Request is created with status "Active" and expiry date
2. After some time request expires
3. Request still exists in DB with the expired date and with status "Active"

Example:

The time now: 13/09/2021 09:56
(Expires day after)

| Status | Expires |
| --- | --- |
| Active | 14/09/2021 09:56 |

Of course, after 1 day the only way to check if the request is expired is to check it against the current time, but the status will still be "Active"

How to change the status of the request to "Expired" if the expiry is determined by the "Expires" field?

Or maybe I chose the wrong approach to do it and don't need the "Expired" status stored in the enum? What is the most convenient way to do this?

Comment: I think you need job for check expire date with your rules

Answer (score 2):

You have a few ways to handle this.

One is to have a regularly running job (say once an hour), which searches for and updates all such entries in the DB.  But this is only as accurate as the frequency at which it runs (e.g.  1 hour), and you probably don't want to run it too often otherwise it could cause performance issues as the Table gets larger.

Some databases support a Time To Live (TTL) feature (such as Mongo, and many Web Service DBs).  This would however normally make the whole record/document invalid and delete it at that point of time.  This probably does not meet your requirements, and the feature is anyway not very common in RDBMS (if at all?)

Another method is to not store the status in the DB directly, but rather just the expiry date and a boolean if it is cancelled.
It is then part of the business logic to determine the state of the entity based on the expiry date.

So then your class could look something like this.

```
public class SomethingRequest
{
    public RequestStatus Status { get { return IsCancelled ? RequestStatus.Cancelled : Expires > DateTime.Now ? RequestStatus.Expired : RequestStatus.Active; } }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
    private bool IsCancelled { get; set; }  //Store cancelled state here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a validation to check the expire time when you check the request, if the request expires then call a helper to update the status.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).